# Vector sum calculation in C++ - Parallel code slower than serial

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, sum, thread-safety

I'm trying to write a multi-threaded code that performs the sum of the elements of a vector.

The code is very simple:

- The threads are defined through a vector of threads;
- The number of threads is defined by the ThreadsSize variable;
- **Using ThreadsSize equal to 1, the sum is performed in about 300ms, while using 8 threads in 1200ms.**

I'm using an HW with 8 cores.

Can someone explain why this happens? Theroetically I would expect to have 300/8 ms in case 8 threads are used. Is it not correct?

Here the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

/* Parallel sum function */
void Function_Sum(mutex& Mutex, vector<double>& Vector, int unsigned kin, int unsigned kend, double& Sum)
{
    for(int unsigned k =kin; k <= kend; k = k + 1)
    {
        Mutex.lock();
        Sum = Sum + Vector[k];
        Mutex.unlock();
    }
}

/* Main function */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Threads and mutex initialization
    int unsigned ThreadsSize = 1;
    vector<thread> Threads;
    mutex Mutex;
    
    // Vector definition
    vector<double> Vector(10000000,1);
    
    // Indexes initialization
    int unsigned kin, kend;
    int unsigned dk = floor(Vector.size() / ThreadsSize);
    
    // Outout 1
    cout << "VectorSize = " << Vector.size() << ", ThreadsSize = " << ThreadsSize << ", dk = " << dk << endl;
    
    // Parallel sum
    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double Sum = 0;
    for(int unsigned k = 0; k <= ThreadsSize - 1; k = k + 1)
    {
        kin = k * dk;
        kend = (k + 1) * dk - 1;
        if(k == ThreadsSize - 1)
        {
            kend = Vector.size() - 1;
        }
        cout << k << " in: " << kin << ", end: " << kend << endl;
        
        Threads.push_back(thread(Function_Sum, ref(Mutex), ref(Vector), kin, kend, ref(Sum)));  
    }
    
    // Threads joining
    for(int unsigned k = 0; k <= ThreadsSize - 1 ; k = k + 1)
    {
        Threads[k].join();
    }
    
    // Elapsed time calculation
    auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double elapsed_time_ms = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end-t_start).count();
    
    // Output 2
    cout << "Sum = " << Sum << endl;
    cout << "Time = " << elapsed_time_ms << endl;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that the actual calculation you're doing is less computationally intensive for your CPU than the overhead of managing the threads?

Comment: If you lock an unlock a mutex common to all threads on every iteration, one could imagine the threads spend more time waiting for a mutex lock than performing (the very cheap) calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small modification of Function_Sum allows to obtain the speedup you desired:

```
double sum = 0.;
for(int unsigned k =kin; k <= kend; k = k + 1)
    sum += Vector[k];
Mutex.lock();
Sum += sum;
Mutex.unlock();
```

Mutex is now being locked once per thread instead of once per addition. If you want a simple explanation, it's just because locking and unlocking mutex costs considerably more than addition.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone explain why this happens? Theoretically I would expect to have 300/8 ms in case 8 threads are used. Is it not correct?

Theoretically, you could get something that is close to `300/8` (plus the overhead of the threads)

But your way of using the mutex completely prevents any parallelization.

```
Mutex.lock();
Sum = Sum + Vector[k];
Mutex.unlock();
```

What you do here is:

1. request a lock so that any other thread has to wait until the mutex is unlocked again
2. do `Sum = Sum + Vector[k];`
3. release the lock so that another thread can gain the lock

So none of the `Sum = Sum + Vector[k];` are done in parallel, and you now have your original 300ms and in addition the overhead of the mutex handling.

What you want to do is to partition your array into 8 parts, sum up those partitions in parallel using an own storage for each thread, and then sum up the results of the 8 threads.

For that divide and conquer approach you actually don't even need a mutex.

You just need a container that has a size of `8` in which you can store the result of each thread.

And after you "join" loop you can iterate over that container and sum the individual sums up.

Or alternatively, you could use `std::future`

So your code would look something like this:

```
#include "math.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

/* Parallel sum function */
double Function_Sum(vector<double> &Vector, int unsigned kin,
                    int unsigned kend) {
  double Sum = 0;
  for (int unsigned k = kin; k <= kend; k = k + 1) {
    Sum = Sum + Vector[k];
  }
  return Sum;
}

/* Main function */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // Threads and mutex initialization
  int unsigned ThreadsSize = 8;
  vector<std::future<double>> Futures;
  mutex Mutex;

  // Vector definition
  vector<double> Vector(10000000, 1);

  // Indexes initialization
  int unsigned kin, kend;
  int unsigned dk = floor(Vector.size() / ThreadsSize);

  // Outout 1
  cout << "VectorSize = " << Vector.size() << ", ThreadsSize = " << ThreadsSize
       << ", dk = " << dk << endl;

  // Parallel sum
  auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  double Sum = 0;
  for (int unsigned k = 0; k <= ThreadsSize - 1; k = k + 1) {
    kin = k * dk;
    kend = (k + 1) * dk - 1;
    if (k == ThreadsSize - 1) {
      kend = Vector.size() - 1;
    }
    cout << k << " in: " << kin << ", end: " << kend << endl;

    Futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&Vector, kin, kend]() {
      return Function_Sum(Vector, kin, kend);
    }));
  }

  // Threads joining

  for (int unsigned k = 0; k <= ThreadsSize - 1; k = k + 1) {
    Sum += Futures[k].get();
  }

  // Elapsed time calculation
  auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  double elapsed_time_ms =
      std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end - t_start).count();

  // Output 2
  cout << "Sum = " << Sum << endl;
  cout << "Time = " << elapsed_time_ms << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Besides that, you in general want to utilize other std functionalities like `std::accumulate`, range-based loops, and iterators. And you shouldn't use `using namespace std`.

With that your code could look like this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  unsigned int ThreadsSize = 8;
  std::vector<std::future<double>> Futures;

  // Vector definition
  std::vector<double> Vector(10000000,1);

  // Indexes initialization
  unsigned int dk = std::floor(Vector.size() / ThreadsSize);

  // Output 1
  std::cout << "VectorSize = " << Vector.size()
            << ", ThreadsSize = " << ThreadsSize << ", dk = " << dk
            << std::endl;

  // Parallel sum
  auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  auto currentIterator = Vector.begin();
  for (unsigned int k = 0; k < ThreadsSize; k++) {
    // save a copy of the current iterator
    auto endIterator = currentIterator;

    if (k == ThreadsSize - 1) {
      // use the actual end iterator for the last thread
      endIterator = Vector.end();
    } else {
      // advance the end iterator
      std::advance(endIterator, dk);
    }

    // create an async task that returns a future
    Futures.push_back(
        std::async(std::launch::async, [currentIterator, endIterator]() {
          // create the sum over the partition
          return std::accumulate(currentIterator, endIterator, 0.0);
        }));

    currentIterator = endIterator;
  }

  // collect the results of the futures
  double Sum = 0;
  for (auto &future : Futures) {
    Sum += future.get();
  }

  // Elapsed time calculation
  auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  double elapsed_time_ms =
      std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end - t_start).count();

  // Output 2
  std::cout << "Sum = " << Sum << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Time = " << elapsed_time_ms << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```